# Are arrays variable-length by default on C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, gcc

I was trying to make an array-based linear list, then I compiled this:

```
char size = 0;
char testarray[10];

int main() { 
    add('a'); add('b'); add('c');
    add('d'); add('e'); add('f');
    add('g'); add('h'); add('i');
    add('j'); add('k'); add('l');
    add('m'); add('n'); add('o');
    print();
    return 0;
} 

void add(char newchar) {
    testarray[++size] = newchar;
}

void print() {
    char i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        printf("%c ", testarray[i]);
    }
 }
```

And compiled it with `gcc arraytest.c` but the array works just fine. Does that mean arrays are variable-length by default? I thought it was a C99-only feature.

It was compiled under both Gentoo (`gcc version 4.5.3 (Gentoo 4.5.3-r2 p1.1, pie-0.4.7`) and Ubuntu (`gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3`).

Oh, and isn't this a bit dangerous?

Comment: Note that, as the term is used in C, "variable-length arrays" still have a static size - just one determined at runtime each time the function is called (and potentially different for each call, but constant throughout the call, after which point the array goes out of scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you are within your allocated range for your application you can use pointers/address wherever you want.  keep going far enough and you either trash your program or hit the edge of your allocated memory and get a protection fault of some sort.  Runtime checking is expensive, wouldnt want to have that anyway.

swap your two variables

```
char testarray[10];
char size = 0;
```

and see what happens when you run it...

And then do this:

```
char size = 0;
char testarray[10];
char stuff[10];
```

before you start adding things to testarray, initialize stuff, then after doing your thing print out the stuff[] array.  You should see your overflow.  In C it is a good rule to put your non-array variables first in the assignment list and the array or arrays last, you have a better chance at debugging.

Answer (score 7):

No, they aren't variable size.  You are just writing past the end of the array and clobbering some other memory.  There are just no checks to make that obvious.

Comment: ... and he is causing undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen, from appearing to work to igniting the atmosphere to buying pizza with your credit card.

Comment: So this is dangerous after all. Oh, okay, thanks. I think I'm a bit too used to Java being overprotective.

Answer (score 5):

#### No

---

Think of C as the world's most awesome assembly language, and it's portable too. It's completely unlike languages designed to be memory-safe. (That would be most of the other ones.)

One way you can answer questions like this (i.e., *"what is C really doing")* is to compile with `cc -S ...` and check the generated assembly code.  Even if you are not familiar with the machine language you can probably tell that it isn't calling or checking subscript range.

C can't ever really do that, as it happens, because `x[i]` is defined as `*(x + i)`, so it really really is a *"high level assembly language"* like they say.

Comment: As someone said in the Lounge<C++> (somewhat facetiously), "C++ has all the power of assembly language and all the convenience of... assembly language."

Comment: @SethCarmegie - [That quote's been around a bit longer than SE Chat has.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie)

Answer (score 2):

As Vaugh said, you are simply "lucky"* in that the memory past the array is writable. There is a chance of a segmentation fault. In fact if you change the program a bit so the array is on the stack, then run it through valgrind it will spit tons of warnings at you.

* "Lucky" in that the program didn't crash. Unlucky in that... it will later.